# Is there any equivalent feature like datalist(html 5) or similar one in pug template engine?

Tags: pug

I have a small form in pug template view.In that I have a particular field where I query from the db and display as options for the user to choose from.But if the option prefered is not available then I want the user to enter manually and submit it.In html5 I have done this using datalist,It's quite simpler.But is there any way to do this with pug view.Please help me with this.

The form looks similar to this

```
    extends layout

    block content
      h1 #{title}
      form(method='POST', action='/projects/reg_project')
        #form-group
          input.form-control(name='name', type='text' placeholder='Name' value=username)
          br
        #form-group
          input.form-control(name='email', type='text' placeholder='Email' value=email)
          br
        #form-group
          input.radio-inline(name='position',type='radio',value='team')
          label Team
          input.radio-inline(name='position',type='radio',value='individual')
          label Lone wolf
          br
        #form-group
<!--right now it is simple text field,I need to change something similar to datalist view -->
          input.form-control(name='teamname', type='text' placeholder='TeamName')
          br
        #form-group
          input.form-control(name='project_title', type='text' placeholder='Project Title')
          br
        #form-group
          textarea.form-control(name='project_description' placeholder='Project Description')
          br
        #form-group
          input(type='checkbox' name='experience') 
          label Done project before
        #form-group
          input(type='checkbox' name='mentor' checked) 
          label Mentor needed

        input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit',value='Submit')
```

Is it possible to do with pug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the same syntax

```
input(id='inp1' list='browsers')

datalist(id='browsers')
    option(value='IE')
    option(value='FF')
```